# Can you run an Java-Spark application (desktop) in a multi-cluster node

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I have implemented a script in Java to process and transform data using Apache Spark. I want to run this script on multiple machines (a multi-cluster node) but I cannot find any documentation on how to do it for a script in Java. So I was wondering if there is anyone here who tried that before because I couldn't find any documentation on it? If it is not possible, then what is the alternative other than changing the code from Java to Scala?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have done a script using spark library (RDD and other things) you just have to send your script to a spark cluster.

And spark will share the execution between the slave by himself.

If your question is how to launch your Spark application on the cluster or how to configure a cluster take a look to [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)